# JNA is unable to get system idle time in ubuntu 11.10 version onwards

Tags: jna, ubuntu-11.10

JNA is unable to get system idle time in ubuntu 11.10 version onwards.

```
    public static long getIdleTimeMillis() {
            X11.Window win = null;
            Xss.XScreenSaverInfo info = null;
            X11.Display dpy = null;

            final X11 x11 = X11.INSTANCE;
            final Xss xss = Xss.INSTANCE;

            long idlemillis = 0L;
            try {
                    dpy = x11.XOpenDisplay(null);
                    win = x11.XDefaultRootWindow(dpy);
                    info = xss.XScreenSaverAllocInfo();
                    xss.XScreenSaverQueryInfo(dpy, win, info);

                    idlemillis = info.idle.longValue();

            } finally {
                    if (info != null)
                            x11.XFree(info.getPointer());
                    info = null;

                    if (dpy != null)
                            x11.XCloseDisplay(dpy);
                    dpy = null;
            }
            return idlemillis;
```

I am using this code to capture idle time. It is working fine in lower versions of ubuntu. but it is not working in latest versions.

It is not moving from the line

final Xss xss = Xss.INSTANCE;

please suggest me a proper solution.

Comment: Can you successfully call these functions from native code?  It's quite possible that your Ubuntu upgrade broke that library or failed to update it properly.

Comment: I am able to call these functions from native code.

Comment: Are you certain there aren't any exceptions being thrown when the library is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, this code works only if "libxss1" package is installed on system.
Since ubuntu 11.10, libXss.so is not installed by default.

sudo apt-get install libxss1
solve this, but require additional system package installation